# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to open the iOS app in Xcode?

Tags: ios, eclipse, macos, sdk, ibm-mobilefirst

I have installed Worklight 6.1.0 in Eclipse Kepler in OS X 10.9.2.

I wish to create a hybrid application in iPhone environment. Generally, creating an iPhone mobile application requires Xcode and iOS SDK. I don't know how to link Xcode with worklight.  Any tutorials or documentation?

Comment: if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as fixed

Answer (score 1):

Sure, plenty of tutorials, see: [IBM Worklight Getting Started training modules](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/).

The steps are:

1. Create new Worklight project
2. Add an application
3. Add the iPhone and/or iPad environment

You can now:

1. Right-click on the iPhone folder and select Run As > Xcode project
   This will build and deploy the app to the Worklight Server + open the generated iOS project in Xcode

Or:

1. Right-click on the app folder and select Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server
   This will build and deploy the app to the Worklight Server.
2. Navigate to the iphone\package folder and copy from it the generated, zipped, Xcode project
   You can now paste it somewhere, like on the Desktop, extract it and double-click the .xcodeproj file to open the project in Xcode

You do not need to link any SDKs. Worklight does most of the job for you. It generates a fully functioning Xcode project containing your web app within, hence a Worklight Hybrid app.

**The above does not replace reading the training material!**